# Unable to update app on heroku: "git add ." gives error

Tags: git, node.js, heroku

"fatal: Unable to create '/Users/apple/documents/herokuapp/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue."

I'm working on thru my Mac Terminal trying to update my app on Heroku.

Comment: Git is one of the few applications that always gives really, really good hints. If it tells us, the lock file can be removed (if no other process is running, which is unlikely on a local repo), you can delete it. Kudos to the guys that made those messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the file. In terminal

```
sudo rm /Users/apple/documents/herokuapp/.git/index.lock
```

Comment: Thanks sir! (can't vote up, i'm new here, and don't have requisite credits)

Comment: No problem, but you can accept this answer so it doesn't show up as unanswered.